# How to create links between vertices in RDD[(Long, Vertex)] based on a property?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have a users: `RDD[(Long, Vertex)]` collection of users. I want to create links between my Vertex objects. The rule is: if two Vertex have the same value in a selected property - call it prop1, then a link exists.

My problem is how to check for every pair in the same collection. If I do:

```
val rels = users.map(
  x => users.map(y => if(x._2.prop1 == y._2.prop1){(x._1, y._1)}))
```

I got back an `RDD[RDD[Any]]` and not a `RDD[(Long, Long)]` as expected for the Graph to work

Comment: You have to write else block for your if so the resulting type to be (Long,Long) - One of the issues

Comment: do you know another way to link together people that share a common attribute?

Comment: sorry but I don't get your previous comment, there is no "else", if they don't match, no link should be returned

Comment: If you don't specify else statement the result type is going to be Any as you specified RDD[RDD[Any]]. So if you don't have else statement you better use collection filter by equal property

Comment: I would group collection of users by prop1. And get desired pairs from groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you cannot start an action of a transformation from an another action or transformation not to mention create nested `RDDs`. So it is simply impossible you get `RDD[RDD[Any]]`.

What you need here is most likely a simple join roughly equivalent to something like this where `T` is a type of the `property1`:

```
val pairs: RDD[(T, Long)] = users.map{ case (id, v) => (v.prop1, id) }
val links: RDD[(Long, Long)] = pairs
  .join(pairs)  // join by a common property, equivalent to INNER JOIN in SQL
  .values  // drop properties
  .filter{ case (v1, v2) => v1 != v2 }  // filter self-links
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I reporter RDD[RDD[Any]] as a consequence of Eclipse error warning: type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any]] required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[?]] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.

Comment: Yeah, never believe IDEs :)

Comment: so now I get that you were not ironical in your message, apology for over-reacting... :)

Comment: Don't worry... Still it is Spark 101  and it is not only about matching types. If it wasn't for that you could simply replace outer `map` with a `flatMap` internal `map` with `filter`.

Comment: @digitaldust Thanks, fixed.

Comment: I just realised that the outcome should be in the form Edge(3L, 7L, "collab") so something like RDD[Edge[]] to feed the graphx constructor... I will accept anyway your answer because it's perfect for my actual question

Comment: You can simply add another `map` after the filter. If you want to keep property and use it as a edge label then remove `values` call an filter / map directly.